# magento2 product collection keeps on loading

Tags: magento2

i was tring to get product collection to show in slider in magento2. i tried

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-product-collection/

to get product collections. but my page keeps on loading. so i commented out everything in the function

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->setPageSize(3); // fetching only 3 products
    return $collection;
}
```

page loaded successfully. So please suggest how i can get product list with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed just by empty the folder var/generation and refreshing the page.